# UIPanGestureRecognizer stays at state begin

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a SpringButton which I want to drag. This is my code:

```
var gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(userDragged))
card.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

var cardIsCurrentlyMoving = false

func userDragged(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    if !cardIsCurrentlyMoving{
        if let button = gesture.view as? SpringButton {
            if gesture.state == .began {
                print("begon")
                cardIsCurrentlyMoving = true
                startPosition = button.center
            } else if gesture.state == .changed {
                print("changed")
            } else if gesture.state == .ended{
                print("ended")
                cardIsCurrentlyMoving = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The function gets called, and the state gets changed to `.began`. However, when trying to move the button nothing happens. This is because `cardIsCurrentlyMoving` is set to true in `.began`, but never back to false, because gesture.state `.changed` and `.ended` never gets called.

When I release my finger and touch the button again, nothing happens as well. Why does `UIPanGestureRecognizer` not executes `.changed` and `.ended`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to check your if statement

```
if !cardIsCurrentlyMoving{ 

}
```

**Pan Gesture continuously calls method with changed state. So userDragged func called continuously** but just because of your above if statement, control doesn't go inside if statement.

So i'll suggest to use this, instead of yours.

```
func userDragged(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer){

        if let button = gesture.view as? SpringButton {
            if gesture.state == .began {
                print("begon")
                cardIsCurrentlyMoving = true
                startPosition = button.center
            } else if gesture.state == .changed {
                print("changed")
            } else if gesture.state == .ended{
                print("ended")
                cardIsCurrentlyMoving = false
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: O this was stupid from me hehe... will accept answer in 4 minutes

Comment: That happens sometimes with me as well :)